# Firebase Functions version of "Deploy to multiple environments"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

As suggested here: "https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html", one should use multiple *projects* (preferably name-differentiated into dev, staging, production, etc) to be able to have a test environment like that on Firebase Hosting.

But again, this document speaks about this approach in the context of Firebase Hosting. Is the same to be followed for Firebase Cloud Functions, if I do not want to update my already live, "production" function before testing the "development" version, or is there an alternate approach which can be followed?

*I don't think I can simply add another Firebase Function, as code would still remain shared between the "production" version and the "development" version, which can cause problems in the "production" version.*

Comment: I'm confused as to how to set this up? Did you ever get it working? I only see docs for setting up `firebase target:apply hosting dev my-dev-project`. Doing this with `functions` does not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: actually I ended up migrating to AWS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of dedicated projects for each enviornment is the same recommended practice for all Firebase products.

Comment: so then I also need to add more projects, with the same plan?

Comment: Each project doesn't have to be on the same plan.  It's very possible that for development, the free quota is good enough.  But you have to figure that out for yourself.

Comment: Yeah, but outbound traffic is not possible on Spark and I needed that.. thanks anyways

Comment: Yes, you'll have to be on Blaze for that, but the good news is that the free tier limits are still free, and you still might not incur any costs.