# Hosting multiple environment in single project in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have one project in firebase and API's hosted using google cloud.
I wanted to understand that how can i host multiple instances of my cloud functions like one with test url , other live , and one may be dev

i tried to deploy by creating sites , but it seems it overwrites and keeps the last one.

i want to avoid creating multiple projects , as it will require multiple databases to be maintained.

Comment: You just want to have multiple endpoints for your Firebase cloud functions to call them?

Comment: You really should use multiple projects, one for each environment.  That's always going to be the recommended solution to keep your environments isolated.  Anything else is going be much more difficult and problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use express to accomplish that. Look at the index.js file on this gitrepo https://github.com/JoeBeer/tandemPartner/tree/master/functions

There you can see how to implement such Endpoints.

EDIT:
Let's assume you want to have an endpoint that you want to call with `https://yourwebsite.cloudfunctions.net/users` and `https://yourwebsite.cloudfunctions.net/chatrooms`.

This could look like as following:

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const express = require('express');

const users = express();
users.use(cors);
let usersEndpoint = require('./usersEndpoint');

const chatrooms = express();
chatrooms.use(cors);
let chatroomsEndpoint = require('./chatroomsEndpoint')

users.post('/', usersEndpoint.createUser); // Create new user
users.put('/:userId', usersEndpoint.updateUser); // Update user
users.delete('/:userId', usersEndpoint.deleteUser); // Delete user
exports.users = functions.https.onRequest(users); // Enables function 'users' @ Cloud Functions

chatrooms.post('/', chatroomsEndpoint.createChatroom); // Create new chatroom
chatrooms.put('/:chatroomId', chatroomsEndpoint.updateChatroom) // Update chatroom
chatrooms.delete('/:chatroomId', chatroomsEndpoint.deleteChatroom) // Delete chatroom
exports.chatrooms = functions.https.onRequest(chatrooms); // Enables function 'chatrooms' @ Cloud Functions
```

Then you have to provide the usersEndpoint.js and chatroomsEndpoint.js.

**usersEndpoint.js**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();
const usersCollection = db.collection('users');

// Creates an user 
exports.createUser = function (req, res) {
    // implement functionality...
};

// Updates an existing user 
exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
    // implement functionality...
};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in this post [1].

In best practice way: "The use of dedicated projects for each enviornment is the same recommended practice for all Firebase products."

[1] [Firebase Functions version of "Deploy to multiple environments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168587/firebase-functions-version-of-deploy-to-multiple-environments)